# how to fill rotated canvas rectangles with image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

my canvas has 4 rectangles and i want to fill each rectangles with an image , for example with i1.png
canvas has been rotated and has scale , when i rotate images they are not on their position. how can i fix it ?

code :

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="black">
    <canvas id="tutorial" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
var canvas = document.getElementById("tutorial"),
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
rects = [
    {x: 0, y: 0, w: 100, h: 100},
    {x: 0, y: 100, w: 100, h: 100},
    {x: 100, y: 100, w: 100, h: 100},
    {x: 100, y: 0, w: 100, h: 100}
],
  i = 0,
  r;
ctx.translate(500, 500);
ctx.scale(0.71, 0.3834);
ctx.rotate(-0.25 * Math.PI);

canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
  var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect(),
    x = e.clientX - rect.left,
    y = e.clientY - rect.top,
    i = 0,
    r;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  while (r = rects[i++]) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(r.x, r.y, r.w, r.h);
 ctx.fillStyle = "#c5de89";
    ctx.fill();
 if(ctx.isPointInPath(x, y)) {
  ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
  ctx.lineWidth = 5;
  ctx.strokeRect(r.x + 5, r.y + 5, r.w - 10, r.h - 10);
  ctx.save();
  base_image = new Image();
  base_image.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3HBL.png';
  ctx.rotate(0.25 * Math.PI);
  //console.log(base_image.width);
  ctx.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0, base_image.width, base_image.height , r.x , r.y , r.w , r.h);
  ctx.restore()
 } else {
  ctx.fillStyle = "#c5de89";
 }
    ctx.save();
    ctx.restore()
  }
};
</script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

My code result :

[image]

i wanna fill my rectangles like this :

[image]

This is our i1.png which used for this example :

[image]

more details (edit):

> I'm trying to create a game map, in fact they created a canvas and
>   rotated that. i want to append my images without any rotates to each
>   rectangles. i think shapes doesn't matter, i just wanna set an image
>   to each rectangle without rotates, when i do this they are no longer
>   in their place! look at second photo , i wanna create something like
>   this. i hope this image make the purpose clear , we split each map
>   block i.stack.imgur.com/kFN6G.jpg , don't consider my codes , think we
>   wanna append an image layer to our shapes!

Comment: At one point you save(), rotate(), and then restore() without actually doing any drawing between the save() and restore(). What's the intended purpose of that bit of code?

Comment: @scg That section is extra, written during testing, and you can skip it.

Comment: Ok. In no way is this intended to be critical, but it might be easier for readers if you could remove any such superfluous code from the example. That way we don't have to try to figure out what is and isn't intended to be relevant.

Comment: @Rishab can you help me to solve this problem

Comment: @Rmanx77, Please create proper [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and remove other unnecessary stuff. Your question, code and expected output seems to disagree with each other. `i created 4 rects and i want to fill them with an image for background of rectangles but i don't know how to set them.` feels you want to insert a rectangle image inside a rotated parallelogram. The output from code you posted is 4 rotated parallelograms but the image for `my code` is already contains the image. `What I want` image differs from what you asked.

Comment: @Sunil post edited.

Comment: @Sunil i wanna fill my rectangles look like second photo.

Comment: It is specific for you to use diamond shape like photo? What I mean is, you can use a [square photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6VAh.png) and it will be easier for you to accomplish the task. Since you create square, scale it, try to fill it with diamond shape photo, rotations etc distort geometry making it difficult to achieve.

Comment: @Sunil I'm trying to create a game map, in fact they created a canvas and rotated that. i want to append my images without any rotates to each rectangles. there isn't any way to do this ?

Comment: @Sunil i think shapes don't matter, i just wanna set an image to each rectangle without rotates, when i do this they are no longer in their place!

Comment: @Sunil look at second photo , i wanna create something like this.

Answer (score 2):

Have tried to achieve the same using square photo
[image: photo]

**Explanation:** canvas green diamond is originally square and photo is also square (maintaining same aspect ratio etc). So all the geometry manipulation on square auto applies to photo and desired result is achived quickly without any manipulation to image

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="black">
    <canvas id="tutorial" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas = document.getElementById("tutorial"),
      ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    rects = [
        {x: 0, y: 0, w: 100, h: 100},
        {x: 0, y: 100, w: 100, h: 100},
        {x: 100, y: 100, w: 100, h: 100},
        {x: 100, y: 0, w: 100, h: 100}
    ],
      i = 0,
      r;
    ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
    ctx.scale(0.71, 0.3834);
    ctx.rotate(-0.25 * Math.PI);

    canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
      var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect(),
        x = e.clientX - rect.left,
        y = e.clientY - rect.top,
        i = 0,
        r;
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      while (r = rects[i++]) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(r.x, r.y, r.w, r.h);
        ctx.fillStyle = ctx.isPointInPath(x, y) ? "red" : "#c5de89";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.save();
    
        base_image = new Image();
        base_image.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6VAh.png';
     //ctx.rotate(0.25 * Math.PI);
        ctx.drawImage(base_image, r.x, r.y, r.w , r.h);
        ctx.restore()
      }
    };
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Let me know if it helps

Comment: i hope this image make the purpose clear , we split each map block https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFN6G.jpg , don't consider my codes , think we wanna append an image layer to our shapes! https://codeshare.io/anVJpE Uploaded the original game js Search 'canvasMap' , maybe i'm wrong!

Comment: i got your message in codeshare , Did you get any results?

Comment: i have been updated my codes , the only problem is x , y locations of image!

Comment: @Rmanx77, Hey buddy! Sorry but am not able to go through this at the time. May be other members will help you out. There are 2 approaches I will suggest you out. Try them on your own.

Comment: 1. For all the diagonal image, create one square image. Then when in game user selects the particular diagonal image, create the canvas texture with the square image using the solution given above. This will involve some initial manual work to save new textures but will definitely help you out.

Comment: 2. If you want to use diagonal image directly, you need to work out the formula. Since you are translating and rotating a square and other image is not rotated; there will be a mathematical formula/pattern involved. Create all 4 squares individually one by one and try to find the relation. This will be trickier than above one.